# Do I really need to move/write entities myself with Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, doctrine-orm

I write my entities in let's say models/ folder.

something like:

```
namespace Organisation\User;
/**
 @Entity
*/
class Customer {

/**
* @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
*/
protected $_id;
}
```

}

So I'll instantiate my entity with `$customer = new \Organisation\User\Customer();`

Ok, but if I use `doctrine orm:generate-entities library/` it will generate it under the following directory :

```
library/Organisation/User/Customer.php
```

ANd that's ok, but if I look at the code, there aren't any of my annotation, and therefore when I try to use it, I get `doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: Class Organisation\User\Customer is not a valid entity or mapped super class.` because there aren't any annotation.

So what I need to do is to remove the namespace, generate into the same  directory as the entities with metadata inforations are, move to my library folder, and add the namespace to work with.

It looks ugly, do I have missed something?

**edit**: <s>I forgot to tell that orm:generate-entities doesn't work recursively, then, I can't even use my actual structure within my entities metadata</s>

Answer (score 0):

If you've written your entity classes already, why are you trying to generate them?

They typical way to drive a new project is to write your annotated entity classes, and use `orm:schema-tool:create` to generate your database schema.

Most examples I've seen do stick the Entities under library/, in some nested directory based on the namespaced name of the class, just as you've described.  This is generally a good thing, as it works with the default Doctrine2 autoloader setup.

If you're not trying to fit Doctrine2 onto an already existing database schema, I'd recommend that you simply stick all your entity classfiles someplace like library//Entity/.php, and use `orm:schema-tool:update` and `orm:schematool:update` to manage the database for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the arg `--generate-annotations`.